# Keras Using Multiple CPU Cores to Generate Data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

The training data for my neural network does not fit in memory. If I use a single core to generate the training data, then it becomes impossibly slow as the data is very big.

I have been reading about Keras.Utils.Sequence and how it is multicore friendly. From what I can see, there little to no documentation on this class. The only helpful example I could find was this:
https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

I still do not understand how I can make multiple cores to contribute to generating a single batch of training data for keras. I absolutely need this to not bottleneck the neural network.

Thank You

Comment: From your link: "Note that our implementation enables the use of the multiprocessing argument of fit_generator, where the number of threads specified in workers are those that generate batches in parallel."

Comment: But in python, threads cannot run on separate cores because of the GIL. I need multiple cores to generate a single batch of data after calling fit_generator.
If I were to do exactly as the link, multiple threads would generate a single batch of training data on a single core and multiple processes would generate multiple batches and that would be too slow for me.

Comment: It uses multiprocessing, which uses multiple processes, not really threads.